# ilmerge error "Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: xxxxxxx"

Tags: c#, ilmerge

I am trying to merge two assemblies using ilmerge with the method described here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx

however, I am getting an error with a project reference I don't want merged...so, of three referenced assemblies, I just want one merged, but the ilmerge doesn't seem to work with the project references.

I know there is a /lib: option, but how can I automate that in the Ilmerge.CSharp.targets so it works with any project?

Answer (score 1):

What error message do you get?

After applying Scott Hanselman's changes to `Ilmerge.CSharp.targets`, manually set `<IlMerge>True</IlMerge>` in your csproj file only on those project references you want merged.

Comment: I think the resolution was that I had to use an earlier version of ilmerge. 2.9.1118

Comment: This only helps if you have checks for the ILMerge tag in the `.targets` file

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem for dll's I *wasn't* merging with ILMerge (I was merging others). It was solved by copying them to the directory `<project>\obj\<configuration>\`, because that's where ILMerge was looking for them and caused the error `Unresolved assembly reference not allowed`.